# Safely rename branch in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, branch, tfs-2015, branching-and-merging

I have a branch created in TFS 2015 that has a lot of work already done, but not yet checked-in.  However, I need to rename the branch now, but I don't want to have to lose or reapply existing updates in order to do so.

Is there a way to safely change the branch name without losing any work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you don't want to checkin before the rename? That sounds like the safest approach.

If not, I would create a shelveset as a backup before renaming. Then when you unshelve you might need to use the TFS Power Tools to do a [`tfpt unshelve /migrate`](http://benjii.me/2014/04/move-shelveset-to-different-branch-in-tfs/).

Comment: The current set of work has much more left to do and I'd prefer to not have numerous changesets for the same update, if I can avoid it.

Comment: Then I'd go with the Shelveset Approach as a backup just in case. I'd actually keep a number of shelvesets if I wasn't checking in regularly as a backup incase my HDD fails